# Multicast sticky observable with on subscribe/on dispose behavior

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to create an `Observable` with the following characteristics:

1. allows multiple concurrent and/or consecutive subscribers
2. emits the last emitted item to every new subscriber
3. does something when the first subscriber subscribes, and when the last subscription is disposed

A `BehaviorSubject` with `doOnSubscribe`/`doOnDispose` satisfies #1 and #2, but runs subscribe/dispose for every subscriber instead of only the first and last. Adding `share` satisfies #1 and #3, but only emits the last emitted item to the first concurrent subscriber.

I came up with a solution that seems to work but feels like an ugly hack:

```
AtomicInteger subs = new AtomicInteger();
Observable<String> test = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("foo")
        .doOnSubscribe(x -> {
            if(subs.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
                // do something
            }
        })
        .doOnDispose(() -> {
            if(subs.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                // do something
            }
        });
```

Is there an existing operator or combination of operators that achieves the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `replay` operator with argument 1 i.e.

```
yourObservable.replay(1)
```

Edit: You are right that replay will return a connectedObservable and that the `refcount` operator will make it behave like on Observable i.e.

```
yourObservable.replay(1).refcount()
```

Comment: That was actually one of the things I tried. The `replay` observable does not emit the initial value of the `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: Aha... `replay` returns a `ConnectableObservable`. The solution is to replace `share()` with `replay(1).refCount()`. Could you edit your answer to include `refCount`?